# Выделение промежуточных checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется таблица, в котором можно выделить некоторые элементы, с помощью `checkbox`.
Как сделать чтобы при выделении, например, 1-го и 4-го объекта (строки), выделались и те, которые идут между ними (т.е 2-ой и 3-ий)

```
<tr class="warning">
    <td class="align-middle" id="{{ downtime[0] }}">
        <input class="big-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle red"></td>
    <td class="align-middle" id="idleTime">{{ downtime[2].strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S') }}</td>
    <td class="align-middle"></td>
    <td class="align-middle"></td>
    <td class="align-middle"></td>
    <td class="nopadding table__button">
         <a type="button" class="btn__table btn__table_dark"><b>Причина</b></a>
    </td> </tr>
```

Comment: А если потом принудительно снять галочку с 3-го?

Comment: @SwaD в таком случае, снять галочку со следующего (4-го), выделенные строки должны идти по порядку

Comment: А если ничего не выбрано и ткнуть на 3й? + потом после третьего ткнуть на 2й? И для нечетных элементов: их 5 штук, тыкаем 3, 5 и потом 1. Что из этого должно раскрасится 1-3 или 1-5?

Comment: В случае если выделено только одно, ничего не делать, останется один выделенный объект. А если  тыкаем 3, 5 и потом 1, должны раскрасятся все, 1-5 соответственно

Comment: Покажите кодом, как устоены ваши чекбоксы в таблице и что не получается сделать?

Comment: у меня пока что нет никакого JS кода, даже не представляю как это реализовать можно)
саму таблицу добавлю к вопросу

Comment: Нажмите кнопку Править под вопросом и в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M, вставьте там ваш код по нужным секциям, обязательно нажмите кнопку "Привести в порядок", после нажмите на "Запустить". Убедитесь, что всё отображается как вам надо и нет никаких других ошибок, кроме тех, о которых вы спрашиваете. Только после всего этого в конце нажмите на "Вставить в сообщение"